# Would it be faster to have an all java program or a perl file that calls different jar files?

Tags: java, performance, perl, time

I have a Perl file that calls several JAR files one after each other. It uses one JAR file output as the input of the other JAR file and so on.

I wonder if I make the whole thing a java program and call different classes o java all by self would it be faster and if yes why?

To explain more, one of the JAR files creates a lot file in a directory and the other JAR file goes and read those file as inputs.

and obviously by faster I mean running time!

Answer (score 1):

Probably.  You'd then only pay the java startup overhead cost once.

But the best way to find out is to benchmark it.